# Avoid memory copies of tensors when when using torch.multiprocessing with CUDA

Tags: pytorch, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I need to parse some datasets in parallel using the same network. The network is on CUDA and I call `share_memory()` before passing it to the parse function. I spawn multiple processes to parse in parallel using `torch.multiprocessing.Pool`.

The GPU usage grows linearly with the number of processes I spawn. I am afraid this is expected, because sharing CUDA models requires the `spawn` start method.
My model is used only for evaluation and runs with `torch.no_grad()` in the spawned function.

Can I prevent this? The same question was asked [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-avoid-copying-data-when-using-multiprocessing-and-cuda/97295) but never got a reply.

Here is a MWE.
With `M = 100` I get CUDA OOM, with 10 I don't.
If I move my model to CPU and use `fork` memory stays constant. Using `spawn` on CPU still increases memory.

```
import signal
import numpy as np
from torch import multiprocessing as mp
import torch
import time

N = 1000
M = 100
DEVICE = 'cuda'
STOP = 'STOP'

data_in = {m: np.random.rand(N) for m in range(M)}
data_out = {m: np.random.rand(N) for m in range(M)}


def initializer():
    """Ignore CTRL+C in the worker process."""
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)


def online_test(queue, model, shared_stats):
    while True: # keep process alive for testing
        # print(f'... {data_id} waiting ...')
        epoch, data_id = queue.get()
        if data_id == STOP:
            print(f'... test function is stopping ...')
            break
        print(f'testing function for {data_id} has started for epoch {epoch}')
        shared_stats.update({data_id: {k: [] for k in ['prediction', 'error']}})
        # print(f'... {data_id} evaluation ...')
        # time.sleep(np.random.randint(1,10))
        pred = model(torch.Tensor(data_in[data_id]).to(device=DEVICE)).cpu().detach().numpy()
        err = pred - data_out[data_id]
        shared_stats.update({data_id: {'prediction': epoch, 'error': - epoch}})
        # shared_stats.update({data_id: {'prediction': list(pred), 'error': list(err)}})
        queue.task_done() # notify parent that testing is done for requested epoch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stats = {**{'epoch': []},
             **{data_id: {k: [] for k in ['prediction', 'error']} for data_id in data_in.keys()}}
    train_model = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(N, N)).to(device=DEVICE)
    test_model = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(N, N)).to(device=DEVICE)
    test_model.share_memory()
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    manager = mp.Manager()
    test_queue = manager.JoinableQueue()
    shared_stats = manager.dict()
    pool = mp.Pool(initializer=initializer)
    for data_id in data_in.keys():
        pool.apply_async(online_test,
            args=(test_queue, test_model, shared_stats))
        test_queue.put((0, data_id)) # testing can start

    try: # wrap all in a try-except to handle KeyboardInterrupt
        for epoch in range(5):
            print('training epoch', epoch)
            # time.sleep(3)
            # ... here I do some training and then copy my parameters to test_model
            print('... waiting for testing before moving on to next epoch ...')
            test_queue.join()
            stats['epoch'].append(epoch + 1)
            test_model.load_state_dict(train_model.state_dict())
            print(f'... epoch {epoch} testing is done, stats are')
            for data_id in shared_stats.keys(): # but first copy stats here
                for k in stats[data_id].keys():
                    mu = np.mean(shared_stats[data_id][k])
                    stats[data_id][k].append(mu)
                    # print('  ', data_id, k, mu)
                test_queue.put((epoch + 1, data_id))

        for data_id in shared_stats.keys(): # notify all procs to end
            test_queue.put((-1, STOP))

        print(stats)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pool.terminate()
    else:
        pool.close()

    pool.join()
```